# How to xml parse text from a tag containing "<?>"

Tags: python, xml, lxml, processing-instruction

My goal is to get the text:
`27. The method according to claim 23 wherein...`
How do I go about retrieving the text inside a tag that contains `<?`. I believe they are called php short tags from googling it.

I am using a lxml, xpaths and they seem to just not register it as a tag or a node. I tried itertext() but that doesnt work as well.

```
 <claim id="CLM-00027" num="00027">
            <claim-text>                <?insert-start id="REI-00005" date="20191203" ?>27. The method according to claim 23 wherein the amorphous metal is selected from the group consisting of Zr based alloys, Ti based alloys, Al based alloys, Fe based alloys, La based alloys, Cu based alloys, Mg based alloys, Pt based alloys, and Pd based alloys.                <?insert-end id="REI-00005" ?></claim-text>
        </claim>
```

Comment: That is invalid “XML”, no?

Comment: It might be invalid. But my parser doesnt throw errors. It just literally returns nothing. Though if you put some text between claim-text and <?insert , it returns the text. Could there be a way to delete the <? ... ?>  so only the text is remaining. Would that be the best approach?

Comment: Did you check if the format is intended to be some other sort of markup language?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It comes from the USTPO Bulk xml dumps. They are like 1-2 GB downloads. Roughly for every 30 claim tags there is one like this.

Comment: @mzjn No i couldnt care for them. Yes those answers were insanely helpful! Thanks

Comment: I think what is meant is that for `<?insert-start?>foo<?insert-end?>`, `foo` should be found.

Comment: @mzjn I think I may have not understood what you were trying to ask me in your previous question. I'll try to clarify, as my question states I want the "text" `<claim-text><?insert-start id="REI-00005" date="20191203" ?>text<?insert-end id="REI-00005" ?></claim-text>` The answers provided ignore the <`?insert-start id="REI-00005" date="20191203" ?>` as you stated. What I meant by "I couldn't care for them" is that I don't care if they ignore it. So the answers were helpful. Are you asking if I am interested in the attributes of the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a piece of code that does that, using XPath to reach the deepest 'valid' tag, and then `getchildren` and `tail` to dive deeper from there all the way to the actual text.

```
import lxml
xml=""" <claim id="CLM-00027" num="00027">
            <claim-text>                <?insert-start id="REI-00005" date="20191203" ?>27. The method according to claim 23 wherein the amorphous metal is selected from the group consisting of Zr based alloys, Ti based alloys, Al based alloys, Fe based alloys, La based alloys, Cu based alloys, Mg based alloys, Pt based alloys, and Pd based alloys.                <?insert-end id="REI-00005" ?></claim-text>
        </claim>"""

root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
e = root.xpath("/claim/claim-text")
res = e[0].getchildren()[0].tail
print(res)
```

Output:

> '27. The method according to claim 23 wherein the amorphous metal is
> selected from the group consisting of Zr based alloys, Ti based
> alloys, Al based alloys, Fe based alloys, La based alloys, Cu based
> alloys, Mg based alloys, Pt based alloys, and Pd based alloys.

Comment: Thanks man! The other answer was great as well. I am doing it the xpath/lxml way so this was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Access specific child nodes by index.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('path_to_your.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

print(root[0].text)
```

output:

```
        27. The method according to claim 23 wherein the amorphous metal is selected from the group consisting of Zr based alloys, Ti based alloys, Al based alloys, Fe based alloys, La based alloys, Cu based alloys, Mg based alloys, Pt based alloys, and Pd based alloys.
```